# Possible to have Drop Shadow on Div Border?

Tags: html, css, dropshadow

Is there a way to get a drop shadow on div borders, using css?

I've created a ribbon effect (see the top, left [ribbon here](http://interruptsoftware.herokuapp.com/)), and I want the drop shadows to apply to the ribbon edges as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. The drop shadow, as with the border, only apply's to the element itself.

I've never seen a css style be applied to another specific css style itself.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but wanted to be sure. Good point, re. you can't style a CSS style itself. Cheers.